# "That": Che vs. Quel

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I apologize if this has already been explained, I've searched both here and elsewhere online and can't find a clarification.

So far as I understand, both "che" and "quel" can mean "that" but they do not seem to be interchangeable.

Is "che" abstract while "quel/quella/etc." is concrete?

The example where I encountered this confusion was while trying to clarify if something I'd said was weird by asking (in Italian) "is that a strange thing to say?" In trying to find which form of "quel" would be appropriate (since I wasn't sure on the gender of the noun) I was told that none were and I should use "che." This is the entirety of what my guess is based on, I've really struggled to find any resource on this at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*That* in English can be used for two different grammatical roles: relative pronoun and determiner. Let me give you examples:

- **Relative pronoun:** This is used to introduce relative clauses, that is clauses that play the role of the subject or object of a different proposition. For example *John is playing a song that his brother loved*, *I did not think that she would go there!*. In this role *that* can sometimes be omitted or replaced by *who*, *which* or *whom*. If the relative clause is connected to the verb by a preposition (e.g. *The person that we were speaking about is here*) you need to translate it with *cui* instead.
- **Determiner:** This is used to specify that you want to talk about *that* thing, not *this* one. For example *I cannot stand that portrait!* or *That is a very good point*. In this role it can often be replaced by *this* (sometimes with a slight change of meaning).

In Italian, *che* always plays the first role while *quello* (or sometimes *ciò*) is used to translate *that* when it plays the second role.

(*Note:* of course there are many more translations of *that*, sometimes it can be translated with *questo* instead, sometimes with something else entirely. This is just a short introduction).

Comment: +1, perfect answer. Let me just add to the note that sometimes the second-type “that” in Italian may disappear altogether and become an implied subject (or whatever). So, for the example by the OP, ”Is that a strange thing to say?” may become simply *È una cosa strana da dire?* (or *Suona strano?*).

Comment: So does that mean what I found originally was incorrect and my example sentence would use quello when translated? It seems to fit your second category.

Comment: @Emmabee: You're right! A literal translation of your sentence could be: "Quello è una cosa strana da dire?" But, as DaG has explained, it's more natural to express this sentence with the subject omitted.

Comment: @Emmabee I suspect they suggested you *Che strana cosa da dire!* which literally means *What a strange thing to say!* (it is a usage of "che" different from the relative pronoun I talked about).

Answer (score 3):

Denis gave a good explanation of that; on top of what he wrote I am giving a couple of more examples "John is playing a song **that** his brother loved" is translated "John suona una canzone **che** il fratello amava"

But "**That** song is wonderful..." is translated "**Quella** canzone è meravigliosa...".

In your specific case, "is that a strange thing to say?",  *thing* (cosa) is feminine and the sentence can be translated with "non è una cosa strana da dire" or (although uncommon) "non è strana da dire questa/quella cosa?"

Che has many meanings and deserves a deeper look and is not the abstract version of quello/a.